# NoReverseMatch in Django Password Reset

Tags: django, django-views

I'm using Django 3.1 and I'm trying to reset the password.
Every step goes fine but one:
After the password reset using
`PasswordResetConfirmView`,
I use success_url to reach the `PasswordCompleteView`, but a NoReverseMatch Error is raised:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/reset/Mjg/set-password/reset/done/` : Mjg/set-password/ always stay in the middle.
How can I remove this ?

The template is the following one:

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}  
{% block title %}Confirmation du Mot de Passe{% endblock %}  
{% block content %} 
<h1>Réinitialisez votre mot de passe</h1>  
{% if validlink %} 
<p> Saisissez votre mot de passe, puis confirmez-le :</p> 
<form method="post">     
{{ form.as_p }}     
{% csrf_token %}     
<p><input type='submit' value='Changer'></p> 
</form> 
{% else %} 
<p>Le lien n'est pas valide. Veuillez renouveler votre demande</p> 
{% endif %}  
{% endblock %}
```

The url path is the following one:

```py
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name="customer/password_reset_confirm.html",
    success_url="reset/done/",
    post_reset_login=True
    ),
    name='password_reset_confirm')
```

and the outcome is:
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/reset/Mjg/set-password/reset/done/`
Thank so much for your help

Comment: Can you please show the template where you constructed the form?

Comment: Can you please Edit your post and update the code in above

Comment: Of course: it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `success_url` must be start with the forward slash `success_url="/reset/done/"`.

But I would use better [**`reverse_lazy`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) - [Django-Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy):

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name="customer/password_reset_confirm.html",
    success_url=reverse_lazy("password_reset_done"),
    post_reset_login=True
    ),
    name='password_reset_confirm')
```

Comment: Thank you NKSM: it worked nicely.
I just needed to complete a little bit the path specified in the success_url with `/customer/` that I added to `reset/done/`
Through your recommendation I could see via Django Debug that `/Mjg/set-password/` had been automatically removed.
Great !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed code to solve this small issue:

```
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name="customer/password_reset_confirm.html",
             success_url="/customer/reset/done/",
             post_reset_login=True),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

It was solved by detailing the success_url.